# I'm getting multiple buttons instead of 1

Tags: html, django

```
<h4>Posts By You</h4>

  {% for i in posts %}
    {% for j in i %}
      <pre id="posts">{{ j }}</pre>
    {% endfor %}
      <div id="delBtnDiv">
      {% for l in postID %}
        {% for k in l %}
          <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" id="delBtn">Delete Post {{ k }}</button>
        {% endfor %}
      {% endfor %}
      </div>

  <hr>

  {% endfor %}
```

---

```
sql = "SELECT postID FROM posts WHERE relUser=%s ORDER BY postID DESC"
        vals = (li)

        cur.execute(sql, vals)
        idResults = cur.fetchall()

        id = []
        id.clear()
        id.append(idResults)

        for idsIndex in range(len(id)):
            for result in results:
                for index in range(len(results)):
                    params = {'name': log_userName, 'noOfPosts': len(result), 'posts': results[index], 'followers': 36, 'pass': log_userPassword, 'postID': id[idsIndex]}
                    return render(request, 'myAccount.html', params)
```

---

[image: I'm getting multiple delete buttons instead of single button Like This]

[image: This is how they come if I place the buttons outside the loop]

The first code snippet is HTML and the second is Django
As seen in the picture I'm getting multiple delete buttons instead of only one, I've used for loops

The second image is when I place the buttons outside the loops

[image: After I've removed 1 for loop]

Comment: So you generate a button in an inner loop and you are surprised you get more than one?

Comment: I want only 1 button with the matching id to the post inside ```<hr>```

Comment: If I'm putting it outside loop it is coming at the very end of the page

Comment: Look at the generated HTML and the CSS - iI do not understand how you are confused.

Comment: I also tried putting it outside the loop but the thing happens is the buttons go to the very bottom of the page

Comment: Why did you post your sql?

Comment: @quantumPuter That should not be of any issue I guess

Comment: You have x number of posts. Your delete button should delete ONE post or ALL "posts by you"?

Comment: @mplungjan only 1

Comment: I think this is a pretty good hint:  .on("click","#delBtn", function(e){ 
        e.preventDefault(); //guess what goes here }

Comment: Anything other than JS?

Comment: `<pre id="posts">{{ j }} <button></button></pre>`

Comment: Nope that doesn't work I've already tried it

Answer (score 0):

Delete the for loop associated with the buttons and instead of k try plugging in straight l in the double curly brackets.

Comment: I'm not going to get proper values if I do that the button text shows "Delete Post (7,)" which cannot be used properly

Comment: Please show the updated code and the results in the post above

Comment: Check it posted